# Kendo stock chart not displayed on IE and firefox

Tags: kendo-ui

Here is the problem I am getting as I am testing with hard code data  to display the stock chart it is working fine in Google chrome and while coming the other browsers like IE and Firefox the graph was not displaying the series legend only the values in x axis and y axis I can able to see with out series.

Comment: Did you try the suggestions in this section? http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/dataviz/troubleshooting

Comment: Yes ,I tried with this but not working .